# Where to place mapping methods in clean architecture

Tags: clean-architecture

I'm developing a web application using .NET 6, C# and clean architecture with 3 projects (Core, Infrastructure and Web).

In the infrastructure layer I have a service that accesses a 3rd party API, let's call it `ApiService`.

In `ApiService` there's a method that does a mapping from one of my domain entities (let's call it `MyEntity`) to an object `MyObject` which is used as payload for a method of the ApiService.

Where would it be correct to place this method? I see several options:
a) In `MyApiService`
b) Somewhere in the Core layer (where exactly? maybe a service-class responsible for the mapping?)
c) any other possibilities?

I have some doubts if placing it in `MyApiService?` would be correct, since the logic of this mapping method has nothing to do with the API calls, so it's not directly related to external infrastructure.

2nd question:
Where does it make most sense to store `MyObject`?
On one hand it's a "stupid" DTO with some [JsonProperty] data annotations and it could easily go into the Core layer.
On the other hand this is used just by the `MyApiService`, so maybe it would make more sense to place it in the Infrastructure layer.

Comment: *"since the logic of this mapping method has nothing to do with the API calls"* - Isn't the exact purpose of the mapping to translate from the domain data structure to the dependency data structure and back?  That would make part of that dependency implementation.

Answer (score 0):

> Where would it be correct to place this method? I see several options: a) In MyApiService b) Somewhere in the Core layer (where exactly? maybe a service-class responsible for the mapping?) c) any other possibilities?

Place it either the `MyApiService` or in an own class, e.g. `ApiServiceMapper` that the `MyApiService` uses. If you put the mapping in a separate class it can be easily tested in isolation.

You should NOT place it in the core layer, because then the core layer has a dependency to the payload objects of your `ApiService`. This would violate the dependency rule. Dependencies should only point inwards not from the core to an outer layer.

> 2nd question: Where does it make most sense to store MyObject? On one hand it's a "stupid" DTO with some [JsonProperty] data annotations and it could easily go into the Core layer. On the other hand this is used just by the MyApiService, so maybe it would make more sense to place it in the Infrastructure layer.

You should NOT put it in the core layer. You already gave the hint: "some JsonProperty annotatios". Since this object is part of the `ApiService` contract, you should place it beside this interface. So put it in the infrastructure layer.